# Combine conditions in an inner if statement with the outer else statement - C#

Tags: if-statement

I have three conditions (a, b, c) to be checked that's supposed to run on the folliwing syntax:

```
if (conditionA)
{
    if (conditionB && conditionC)
    {
        // Execute();
    }
}
else if (conditionC)
{
    // Execute();
}
```

Better still, can these conditions be simplified to one line, so that `Execute()` will end up in one set of braces? Thanks.

Comment: if ((conditionA && conditionB && conditionC) || ConditionC)

Comment: Hey @ecg8, thanks but in my condition, `conditionC` won't have to be checked anymore once `conditionB` is `false`.

Comment: Yo @ecg8, my snippet does indicate it as is. `conditionC` in the inner if block will not be checked since it is short-circuited (and therefore does not enter the `Execute()` within. The outer `conditionC` on the `else if` will be skipped since it has already returned true for `conditionA` which is needed to go to `conditionB`. Hope this is not too confusing :P

Comment: how about if ((conditionA && conditionB && conditionC) || (!conditionA && conditionC))

Answer (score 0):

The first condition can be simplified to `if (conditionA && conditionB && conditionC)`
unless there is some processing or `conditionB`/`conditionC` are calculated between the first `if` and the second.

If the conditions are all available up front you could do something like:

```
if((conditionA && conditionB && conditionC)||(conditionC))
{
    // Execute();
}
```

This will look at the first set of inner braces `(conditionA && conditionB && conditionC)` which will only return true if A, B and C are **all** `true`, then evaluate `conditionC` and if either of these return `true`, it will enter into the block and perform the `Execute()` function.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work; in my scenario if `conditionB` is `false`, it won't get to either `conditionC` check anymore.

Comment: I would need to know a bit more about to code to comment on that, but in the scenario of A = true, B = false, C = true. This would go through and call `Execute()`

Comment: In your code, if you put the a-b-c parentheses into say `d`, and check with `conditionC`, then that would make `d || c` which means, `conditionC` will still be checked once `d` is false. I've checked it :D

Comment: I guess the thing is once `conditionB` is false on that inner `if`, `conditionC` must not be checked anymore.